# I am getting error while upload the .txt extension file and .doc extension files

Tags: php, file-upload

I am making  a web form for teachers where student can submit there assignment and teacher can check. but i am getting error i can not upload the .txt and .doc i am having probelm in my code here is my effort.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
if ($_POST["upload"] == "1") {

    if ((($_FILES['file']['type'] == ".txt") || ($_FILES['file']['type'] == ".doc")) && ($_FILES['file']['size'] > "0")) {
        $id = 4881;
        $name = "Naeem";
        /*first image folder i i showed abd get file and move*/
        $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $fileName = preg_replace('#[^a-z.0-9]#i', '', $fileName);
        $kaboom = explode(".", $fileName);
        // Split file name into an array using the dot
        $fileExt = end($kaboom);
        // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
        $fileName = $id . "(" . time() . rand() . ")." . $fileExt;
        $to = "file/" . $fileName;

        /*this step is used to move file from tmp to a folder*/
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $to)) {
            if ($query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `file` (
                                        `id` ,
                                        `std_id` ,
                                        `std_name` ,
                                        `file_url`
                                        )
                                        VALUES (
                                            NULL , '" . $id . "', '" . $name . "', '" . $to . "'
                                        );"))
            {
                echo "Uploaded succesfully";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let me review your code

Comment: Be careful never trust the user! Here you don't verify the mimetype of the received files so people can send php code!

Comment: The `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` should be behind the first appearance of the php open tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have minor mistake in your code that you have put wrong extension.

```
if((($_FILES['file']['type']=="text/plain") || ($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/msword"))&&($_FILES['file']['size']>"0"))
```

It is not .txt and .doc it is **text/plain** for text files and for .doc it is **application/msword**.
I hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the issue -

```
(($_FILES['file']['type']==".txt") || ($_FILES['file']['type']==".doc"))
```

**File Extension** and **MIME Type** are not same.

Replace `.txt` by `text/plain` And `.doc` by `application/msword`.

Comment: Oh i see now what to do.