# php save image with specific file name not overwriting each other

Tags: php, image, save, base64

I hope someone can help me with this php code.
At the moment its just saving an image with the file name "img.png" to the server but with every time a new canvas screenshot is taken the image is just overwritten.

My aim is to create a new unique (like numbered chronological by time taken) file name for the images with every new screenshot and save it on the server.

Here the php code so far:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['base64data']; 
echo $data;

$image = explode('base64,',$data); 

file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($image[1]));
```

Thank you.
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$filename = 'img_'.date('Y-m-d-H-s').'.png';
file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($image[1]));
```

This will save your file with a filename containing the current date and time, e.g.

```
img_2013-09-19-21-50.png
```

Comment: perfect thx.
Is it also possible to get the IP of the user who clicked or unique browser data to implement into the file name?

Comment: You might want to include information from [the PHP `$_SERVER` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). For example: `$filename = 'img_'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'.png';`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a session variable to increment a counter like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])){
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['counter']++;

$data = $_REQUEST['base64data']; 
echo $data;

$image = explode('base64,',$data); 

file_put_contents('img'.$_SESSION['counter'].'.png', base64_decode($image[1])); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do it, but the easiest is just to add a timestamp/datestamp to the image name. Format the name as you want.

```
$img_name = 'img'.date('YmdHisu').'.png'; // Date & time with microseconds
$img_name = 'img'.time().'.png'; // unix timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the base64data structure use this one it will work fine.

```
$fileName = preg_replace('#[^a-z.0-9]#i', '', $fileName); 
$image = explode(".", $fileName);
```

It will give a random number to each image file.

Comment: How would this give the filename a random number? This would only remove all letters and numbers from the filename, wouldn't it?

Comment: because i have did it thats why it will give.

Comment: the name will remain the same but in front of name you will get a random number each time you will upload the image or some file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739864/i-am-getting-error-while-upload-the-txt-extension-file-and-doc-extension-files/18739961#18739961

Comment: see this code and you will get clear what i wanted to provide

Comment: You are wrong! This is the line that creates the random number into your filename: `$fileName = $id . "(" . time() . rand() . ")." . $fileExt;`.

Comment: bro i think you are not getting me i am saying that the file name will remain the same but in the bracket the random number will be change .

Comment: You're making my argument here :-)

Comment: because you are not getting me although

Comment: Your code does nothing, but splitting the filename by the dot. [See here](http://codepad.org/LMzTNfxd). But [look what it does](http://codepad.org/EcLp4LBC) when you add the line I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: and above your comment i have given a link where you can see the whole program. if you dont mind go ahead and check it

Answer (score 0):

either create a UID using uniqid() function for the filename or create a folder with the name of the username who is uploading the file and leave the original filename. The disadvantage of the first one is that you will have to save the original filename somewhere to show to the user.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371988/2701758

Answer (score 0):

**

```html
 
 /* simply for local time first give your continent then '/' then your country's 
 capital.
*/ 
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
    
    $now = new DateTime();
    $now = $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
    
    $new_name = $now.$image;
  /*what you want to add just write with dot,such 
    $new_name = 'img'.$now.$image;
   */
```

**